# how to build Expression<Func<x,y>> with no input parameters?

Tags: linq

I use `Expression.Call` to build MethodCallExpression dynamically. The call is for "First" method.
Then, I need to wrap it to `Expression<Func<x,y>>` (x and y are types, and it irrelevant to the question). I'm trying to do it with `Expression.Lambda<Func<x,y>>`, but get `Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration` exception when passing
 `new ParameterExpression[]{}` (i.e. empty array) in the ParameterExpression[] input parameter.
what should be provided to `Expression.Lambda` when the Lambda takes ZERO parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) is the delegate that corresponds to a `void` that accepts no parameters.  `Func<x, y>` says that the method accepts an `x` and returns a `y`.  All the `Func` delegates return values, and all the `Action` delegates are `void`.